# How to open a stored in SharePoint from Team System task screen?

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2010, tfs

Someone put a hyperlink to a document stored in SharePoint, in the *All Links* tab of a TFS task.

When I double click it, it opens up in a new browser tab in VS2010, then asks whether to download it ("Open/Save" dialog).
The result is that the file is downloaded and then opened as a local copy.

What I want to do is to open the document **directly** from the URL of the SharePoint site so editing will be done directly.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would asume that if you select "Open" that it would open off the sharepoint server. If this is not the case, then you would need to navigate to that document in Team Explorer or on the Sharepoint site and open it from there.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for the answer! Indeed this is not the case. My client is looking for a solution for it to open directly from the TFS task and not by browsing to it.